# Set default scroll position

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

How can I automatically scroll a WebView to a specific coordinate of the window upon load? I am using Swift. Running on MacOS Sierra. I have tried various methods found from Google without success.

Edit:
It's actually a WKWebView so that changes things since they don't have the same methods.

I'm getting the following error:

> Value of type 'WKWebView' has no member 'scrollView'

Comment: Have you tried using `webView.scrollView.contentOffset`?

Comment: set the contentOffset in webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: It's actually a WKWebView so that changes things since they don't have the same methods.

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "Value of type 'WKWebView' has no member 'scrollView'"

Comment: The scrollView property is IOS only.  See that on the scrollView page.